# Why am I getting two different values for the same arithmetic operation with the same numbers?

Tags: python

I'm doing a very simple hourglass sum function that adds up values in a 2d matrix in Python. While computing the sum, my printed statement gets one value, while putting it into a variable gets another value.

```py
def hourglassSum(arr):
    max_sum = 0

    for row in range(1, len(arr) - 1):
        for col in range(1, len(arr[row]) - 1):
            print('Printed Sum', arr[row][col] + arr[row - 1][col] 
            + arr[row - 1][col - 1] + arr[row - 1][col + 1] + arr[row + 1][col] 
            + arr[row + 1][col - 1] + arr[row + 1][col + 1])

            computed_sum = arr[row][col] + arr[row - 1][col] 
            + arr[row - 1][col - 1] + arr[row - 1][col + 1] + arr[row + 1][col] 
            + arr[row + 1][col - 1] + arr[row + 1][col + 1]

            print('Computed Sum',computed_sum)

            if computed_sum > max_sum:
                max_sum = computed_sum
    return max_sum
```

I would expect the computed_sum to be the same that gets printed out. However my output shows two completely different numbers every loop.

I'm very new to python so I'm sure I either missed a dumb little bug, or there is something I'm not understanding. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The second expression is cut off by the line break. In Python line breaks are not syntax relevant as long as any kind of bracket is still open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statements in Python usually end at a new-line. Therefore

```
computed_sum = arr[row][col] + arr[row - 1][col]
```

is evaluated completely separately from the following to statements

```
+ arr[row - 1][col - 1] + arr[row - 1][col + 1] + arr[row + 1][col] 
+ arr[row + 1][col - 1] + arr[row + 1][col + 1]
```

These are two statements summing variables, but doing nothing with the result. The first `+` is an unary `+` operator.

With the `print(` at the beginning of

```
print('Printed Sum', arr[row][col] + arr[row - 1][col]
```

the statement has to continue into the next lines, because there is still an open `(` at the new-line. So the following two lines are evaluated as part of the expression. Only the `)` with a following new-line ends the statement.

You can avoid this problem by putting parantheses around the whole expression:

```
computed_sum = (arr[row][col] + arr[row - 1][col] 
             + arr[row - 1][col - 1] + arr[row - 1][col + 1] + arr[row + 1][col] 
             + arr[row + 1][col - 1] + arr[row + 1][col + 1])
```

Or you can put `\` before the problematic line breaks to instruct Python to consider the following line a continuation of the current one (basically ignoring the new-line).